# 301 redirects creating "The page isn't redirecting properly" error in browsers

Tags: http-status-code-301

We have a site where the domain name has changed:

On the virtual host for the old domain we're redirecting like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName old-domain.com
  Redirect permanent / http://www.new-domain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.old-domain.com
  Redirect permanent / http://www.new-domain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Then we have a bunch of redirects in the .htaccess file for the new site like this:

```
Redirect 301 /about-us /about-us/about-us/
```

But some pages cause redirect errors in the browser. e.g. this redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /current-vacancies /about-us/recruitment/
```

Outputs this:

```
http://www.new-domain.com/about-us/about-us//about-us//about-us//about-us//about-us//about-us//about-us//about-us//about-us//about-us//about-us//about-us//about-us//about-us//about-us//about-us//about-us//about-us//recruitment/
```

Can anyone see what we've done wrong?

Cheers

Ben

Comment: Actually, is my /about-us redirect causing a loop?

Comment: If I remove the /about-us redirect, the other redirects now work. How do you redirect: /about-us /about-us/about-us/ without causing a loop? Cheers